# How to set my Qt application load dlls in a different folder?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

How to set my qt project to search for the dependent DLLs in a different folder than the exe folder?

I can't compile it as static because I'm using the `QWebEngine` module which didn't support being built statically.

These are some things I already tried:

Creating a [qt.conf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-conf.html) file in the same folder of the exe and specifying a path.

```
[Paths]
Prefix = D:/Project/New folder
```

[SetDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya), [addLibraryPath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath)

```
    //SetDllDirectory(L"D:/Project/New folder"); 

    //QList<QString> list = {"D:/Project/New folder"};
    //QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths(list);

    QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("D:/Project/New folder");

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

I was not sure when to call these 3 options, I tried calling then before the `QApplication`  line.

I have been able to deploy it using `windeployqt`, the project is being built using `Qt 6.4` and `Visual Studio 2019`.

Comment: Are you deploying your app with something like CQtDeployer or just building locally?

Comment: @perivesta i tried `CQtDeployer` but i didn't understand how to use it, then I tried with `windeploy` and it did work, however i would like to let the dependencies in a different folder: https://i.imgur.com/3WZF0L9.png

Comment: Looks like windeployqt's `--libdir` option is what you want?

Comment: @perivesta i tried it, it put the dlls in a different folder, however when i run the exe it doesnt find the dlls.